# How To Create Nested View Link In JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

How To Create Nested View Link In JDeveloper
For Example I only create one view link contains
three things like

```
      Master Table
           MobilePurchaseSearchDate
                Details Table
                     MobilePurchaseSearchName
                          Details Table
                              MobilePurchaseSearchModel
```

How to create this nested view link plz tell me
:(

Answer (score 0):

You create view links from 1->2 and from 2->3
Then in the application module data model you can shuttle the VO's to the right.
First shuttle 1, then stand on it on the right side and shuttle 2 under that one, and then stand on 2 and shuttle 3 under that one.